# parameter of Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new Uri(var)) so that it doesn't open anything

Tags: url, xamarin.forms

For a customer need, we have an url that is gotten from an API and they ask me if they can replace the url by anything to temporary disable a feature without having to publish a new app version (they can't for now).

I tried

```
this.Url = String.Empty;
Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new Uri(this.Url));
```

but it crashes.

Is there something they can set the Url to in the API so the TryOpenAsync line will just do nothing without crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the logic in a **try-catch** statement .

```
try
{
  Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new Uri(""));
}         
catch(UriFormatException e)
{
    // ... do something you want 
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I know perfectly how I can fix this. But I can't edit the code as they don't want to release a new version of the app until January until they have to. But thanks for you time anyway :)